# iPhone not connecting to cellular service

Tags: iphone, sim

For about two weeks now the service bar on my iPhone 7 Plus only says searching. I contacted my service provider and they said it was the SIM card but I switched my SIM card with another iPhone user and they had service and when I put my SIM card in their phone I still had no service. I then tried to restart everything and connect it to my computer, so I can erase everything on my iPhone, yet it says it needs a SIM card and I had my SIM card in my iPhone with still no service.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Generally we prefer to keep questions public, and not switch to email, this is because then other people with your problem in the future can see what solutions other people tried, but also those who put their time into trying to help resolve your answer get points as a reward if their answer is marked as a solution. By switching to a private email none of these benefits can be seen.

Comment: Have you tried resetting iPhone?  You may lose some things in the process.

Comment: Are you referring to a wireless service you use? Which one if you don't mind sharing the info.

Comment: @jmh My phone has been reseted to where you get the screen where it asked you for your wifi and stuuf but it wont let any service connect to it because i have no service and i have at&t